# "Everything is a Map", am I doing this right?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, functional-programming

I watched Stuart Sierra's talk "[Thinking In Data](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Thinking-in-Data)" and took one of the ideas from it as a design principle in this game I'm making. The difference is he's working in Clojure and I'm working in JavaScript.  I see some major differences between our languages in that:

- Clojure is idiomatically functional programming
- Most state is immutable

I took the idea from the slide "Everything is a Map" (From 11 minutes, 6 seconds to > 29 minutes in).  Some things he says are:

1. Whenever you see a function that takes 2-3 arguments, you can make a case for turning it into a map and just passing a map in.  There are a lot of advantages to that:

   1. You don't have to worry about argument order
   2. You don't have to worry about any additional information.  If there are extra keys, that's not really our concern.  They just flow through, they don't interfere.
   3. You don't have to define a schema
2. As opposed to passing in an Object there's no data hiding.  But, he makes the case that data hiding can cause problems and is overrated:

   1. Performance
   2. Ease of implementation
   3. As soon as you communicate over the network or across processes, you have to have both sides agree on the data representation anyway.  That's extra work you can skip if you just work on data.
3. **Most relevant to my question. This is 29 minutes in:** "Make your functions composable". Here's the code sample he uses to explain the concept:

   ```
   ;; Bad
   (defn complex-process []
     (let [a (get-component @global-state)
           b (subprocess-one a) 
           c (subprocess-two a b)
           d (subprocess-three a b c)]
       (reset! global-state d)))

   ;; Good
   (defn complex-process [state]
     (-> state
       subprocess-one
       subprocess-two
       subprocess-three))
   ```

   I understand the majority of programmers aren't familiar with Clojure, so I'll rewrite this in imperative style:

   ```
   ;; Good
   def complex-process(State state)
     state = subprocess-one(state)
     state = subprocess-two(state)
     state = subprocess-three(state)
     return state
   ```

   Here are the advantages:

   1. Easy to test
   2. Easy to look at those functions in isolation
   3. Easy to comment out one line of this and see what the outcome is by removing a single step
   4. Each subprocess could add more information on to the state.  If subprocess one needs to communicate something to subprocess three, it's as simple as adding a key/value.
   5. No boilerplate to extract the data you need out of the state just so that you can save it back in.  Just pass in the whole state and let the subprocess assign what it needs.

Now, back to my situation:  I took this lesson and applied it to my game.  That is, almost all of my high level functions take and return a `gameState` object.  This object contains all the data of the game.  EG: A list of badGuys, a list of menus, the loot on the ground, etc.  Here's an example of my update function:

```
update(gameState)
  ...
  gameState = handleUnitCollision(gameState)
  ...
  gameState = handleLoot(gameState)
  ...
```

What I'm here to ask about is, **have I created some abomination that perverted an idea that is only practical in a functional programming language?**  JavaScript isn't *idiomatically* functional (though it can be written that way) and it's really challenging to write immutable data structures.  One thing that concerns me is he *assumes* that each of those subprocesses are pure. Why does that assumption need to be made?  It's rare that any of my functions are pure (by that, I mean they often modify the `gameState`.  I don't have any other complicated side effects other than that).  Do these ideas fall apart if you don't have immutable data?

I'm worried that one day I'll wake up and realize this whole design is a sham and I've really just been implementing the [Big Ball Of Mud anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).

---

Honestly, I've been working on this code for months and it's been great.  I feel like I'm getting all the advantages he's claimed.  My code is super easy *for me* to reason about.  But I'm a one man team so I have the curse of knowledge.

## Update

I've been coding 6+ months with this pattern. Usually by this time I forget what I've done and that's where "did I write this in a clean way?" comes into play. If I haven't, I'd really struggle. So far, I'm not struggling at all.

I understand how another set of eyes would be necessary to validate its maintainability. All I can say is I care about maintainability first and foremost. I'm always the loudest evangelist for clean code no matter where I work.

I want to reply directly to those that already have a bad personal experience with this way of coding.  I didn't know it then, but I think we're really talking about two different ways of writing code.  The way I've done it appears to be more structured than what others have experienced.  When someone has a bad personal experience with "Everything is a map" they talk about how hard it is to maintain because:

1. You never know the structure of the map that the function requires
2. Any function can mutate the input in ways you'd never expect.  You have to look all over the code base to find out how a particular key got into the map or why it disappeared.

For those with such an experience, perhaps the code base was, "Everything takes 1 of N types of maps." Mine is, "Everything takes 1 of 1 type of map". If you know the structure of that 1 type, you know the structure of everything.  Of course, that structure usually grows over time.  That's why...

There's one place to look for the reference implementation (ie: the schema). This reference implementation is code the game uses so it can't get out of date.

As for the second point, I don't add/remove keys to the map outside of the reference implementation, I just mutate what's already there. I also have a large suite of automated tests.

If this architecture eventually collapses under its own weight, I'll add a second update.  Otherwise, assume everything is going well :)

Comment: Cool question (+1)! I find it a very useful exercise to try and implement functional idioms in a non-functional (or not very strongly functional) language.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/174968/421245, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842020/421245

Comment: Anyone who's going to tell you that OO-style information hiding (with properties and accessor functions) is a bad thing because of the (usually negligible) performance hit, and then tell you to turn all of your parameters into a map, which gives you the (much greater) overhead of a hash lookup every time you try to retrieve a value, can be safely ignored.

Comment: @MasonWheeler lets say you are right about this.  Are you going to void every other point he makes because of this one thing is wrong?

Comment: In Python (and I believe most dynamic languages, including Javascript), object is really just syntax sugar for a dict/map anyway.

Comment: @LieRyan - From a linguistic level, yes.  How ever, at the implementation level you can be sure that high performance implementations do their best to turn the conceptual dict / map into something more efficient.

Comment: @MattFenwick Are you expecting the bad/Clojure and good/imperative to be similar?  There's a reason I wrote `;;good` above the imperative. It's supposed to be similar to the good/Clojure

Comment: @tieTYT let me try again.  In the bad Clojure example, you pass `a` to `subprocess-one`, `a` and `b` to `subprocess-two`, and `a`, `b`, and `c` to `subprocess-three`.  In the good imperative example, you only pass the `state` argument.  What happened to `a`, `b`, and `c` -- are you saying that `state` is a map with those keys?  If so, sorry for bothering you and it makes sense now.

Comment: @MattFenwick Yes I'm saying that.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds horrible to me. And the comment about needing "another set of eyes" is the clincher - developers should never work for more than 6 months solo without even an hour or two of code review. I can't count the number of things I've written that I *thought* were totally intuitive because I wrote it and obviously understood every implementation detail, but it turned out that nobody else could make any sense of. It's also not very good manners to ask for feedback, disregard that feedback, and then proceed to claim at length that everyone who replied misunderstood the question.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Correct me if I'm wrong but map/dict lookups happen in O(N) time. Where is this mysterious performance hit that you speak of?

Comment: @EvanPlaice: Big-O notation can be deceptive.  The simple fact is, *anything* is slow compared to direct access with two or three individual machine code instructions, and on something that happens as often as a function call, that overhead will add up very quickly.

Comment: On your update:  Global stores have become a common thing in javascript, by way of libraries like redux.  You've implemented the same concept. Your various update functions are basically equivalent to redux reducers, just not nested.

Comment: @Izkata I know, weird!  And elm is very similar in this respect.

Comment: "I don't add/remove keys to the map outside of the reference implementation, I just mutate what's already there."

Then why not just use an object?

Comment: @KevinVanDyck I don't understand the question.  In JS, an object can be used as a map.  IMO, I am using an object.

Comment: "almost all of my high level functions take and return a gameState object. This object contains all the data of the game. EG: A list of badGuys, a list of menus, the loot on the ground, etc."  To me, this doesn't sound like a map.  This sounds like you're passing around a big ol' wad of global data.  However, I also get the impression you may be coding in XNA, and I suspect what you're doing isn't entirely unreasonable for XNA.  GameState really is a big ol' wad of data that gets affected by just about everything.

Answer (score 43):

I've supported an application where 'everything is a map' before. It's a terrible idea. PLEASE don't do it!

When you specify the arguments that are passed to the function, that makes it very easy to know what values the function needs.  It avoids passing extraneous data to the function that just distracts th programmer - every value passed implies that it's needed, and that makes the programmer supporting your code have to figure out why the data is needed.

On the other hand, if you pass everything as a map, the programmer supporting your app will have to fully understand the called function in every way to know what values the map needs to contain.  Even worse, it's very tempting to re-use the map passed to the current function in order to pass data to the next functions.  This means that the programmer supporting your app needs to know all functions called by the current function in order to understand what the current function does.  That's exactly the opposite of the purpose for writing functions - abstracting problems away so that you don't have to think about them!  Now imagine 5 calls deep and 5 calls wide each.  That's a hell of a lot to keep in your mind and a hell of a lot of mistakes to make.

"everything is a map" also seems to lead to using the map as a return value.  I've seen it.  And, again, it's a pain.  The called functions need to never overwrite each other's return value - unless you know the functionality of everything and know that the input map value X needs to be replaced for the next function call.  And the current function needs to modify the map to return it's value, which must sometimes overwrite the previous value and must sometimes not.

**edit - example**

Here's an example of where this was problematic.  This was a web application.  User input was accepted from the UI layer and placed in a map.  Then functions were called to process the request.  The first function set would check for erroneous input.  If there was an error, the error message would be put in the map.  The calling function would check the map for this entry and write the value in the ui if it existed.

The next function set would start the business logic.  Each function would take the map, remove some data, modify some data, operate on the data in the map and put the result in the map, etc.  Subsequent functions would expect results from prior functions in the map.  In order to fix a bug in a subsequent function, you had to investigate all prior functions as well as a the caller to determine everywhere the expected value might have been set.

The next functions would pull data from the database.  Or, rather, they'd pass a the map to the data access layer.  The DAL would check if the map contained certain values to control how the query executed.  If 'justcount' was a key, then the query would be 'count select foo from bar'.  Any of the functions that was previously called might have ben the one that added 'justcount' to the map.  The query results would be added to the same map.

The results would bubble up to the caller (business logic) which would check the map for what to do.  Some of this would come from things that were added to the map by the initial business logic. Some would come from the data from the database.  The only way to know where it came from was to find the code that added it.  And the other location that can also add it.

The code was effectively a monolithic mess, that you had to understand in it's entirety to know where a single entry in the map came from.

Comment: Your second paragraph make sense to me and that really sounds like it sucks.  I'm getting the sense from your third paragraph that we aren't really talking about the same design though.  "re-use" is the point. It'd be wrong to avoid it. And I really can't relate to your last paragraph.  I have every function take the `gameState` without knowing anything about what happened before or after it.  It simply reacts to the data it's given.  How did you get into a situation where the functions would step on each others toes?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I added an example to try and make it a little clearer.  Hope it helps.  Also, there's a difference between passing around a well defined state object versus passing around a blob that sets changed by many places for many reasons, mixing ui logic, business logic, and database access logic

Answer (score 28):

Personally, I wouldn't recommend that pattern in either paradigm.  It makes it easier to write initially at the expense of making it more difficult to reason about later.

For example, try to answer the following questions about each subprocess function:

- Which fields of `state` does it require?
- Which fields does it modify?
- Which fields are unchanged?
- Can you safely rearrange the order of the functions?

With this pattern, you can't answer those questions without reading the entire function.

In an object oriented language, the pattern makes even less sense, because tracking state is what objects do.

Comment: "the benefits of immutability go way down the larger your immutable objects get"  Why? Is that a comment on performance or maintainability?  Please elaborate on that sentence.

Comment: @tieTYT Immutables work well when there's something small (a numeric type for example). You can copy them, create them, discard them, flyweight them with rather low cost.  When you start dealing with entire game states made up of deep and large maps, trees, lists, and dozens if not hundreds of variables, the cost to copy or delete it goes up (and flyweights become impractical).

Comment: I see.  Is that a "immutable data in imperitive languages" issue or a "immutable data" issue?  IE: Maybe this isn't an issue in Clojure code.  But I can see how it is in JS.  It's also a pain to write all the boilerplate code to do it.

Comment: @MichaelT and Karl:  to be fair, you should really mention the other side of the immutability/efficiency story.  Yes, naive usage can be horribly inefficient, that's why people have come up with better approaches.  See Chris Okasaki's work for more information.

Comment: @MattFenwick I personally quite like immutables.  When dealing with threading I know things about the immutable and can work and copy them safely.  I put it in a parameter call and pass it to another without worrying that someone will modify it when it comes back to me. If one is talking about a complex game state (the question used this as an example - I would be horrified to think of something as 'simple' as nethack game state as an immutable), immutability is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: @MichaelT perhaps we are talking past each other.  My point is that "large functional data structures are inefficient, end of story", which I believed the answer and your comment were stating, is too simplistic and wrong.  Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @MichaelT It should be noted that languages that put a priority on immutability can implement them in such a way that you don't actually have to copy the state to update it. If I add an element onto an immutable list in a functional language, the new list I get back is *not* that element plus a copy of the original list - it just re-uses the original as part of the new list with both lists referring to the same memory. This isn't a problem because the data is immutable and thus you'll never mutate it and change both lists. So large immutable trees are actually not inefficient.

Comment: @Jack ... Until you try to garbage collect it and find lots of things using parts of the structure preventing it from being collected. This was an issue in earlier versions of String in Java, where substring would use part of the larger string. Getting the first letter of a 1MB string would keep that larger string in memory even if the original ref was lost. There are trade offs in design one has to think about. This is likely part of the reason they are used less - it sometimes takes more thought power.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue of shoddy implementation than a problem with the underlying concept. There are shoddy implementations of mutable data structures too, that doesn't say much of anything about the *entire practice* of using mutable structures.

Comment: @Jack You can see it in [String(int, int, char)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%29) in Java 6b14. It's the *right* answer for many situations... until people stuck a megabyte of xml in a String and then passed around chunks of it. The point I was trying to make was that choosing the right implementation for an immutable data structure requires thinking about the data differently, and often in ways one hasn't thought of before if one is just coming to immutable data.

Comment: The tradeoffs of speed (how about a O(1) for creating a substring vs O(n)?) and memory are not ones that people who have worked with mutable structures have considered. With mutable data, you are working with it in a way you are likely familiar with and have years of experience doing so and can quickly recognize the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 12):

What you seem to be doing is, effectively, a manual State monad; what I would do is build a (simplified) bind combinator and re-express the connections between your logical steps using that:

```
function stateBind() {
    var computation = function (state) { return state; };
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i++ ) {
        var oldComp = computation;
        var newComp = arguments[i];
        computation = function (state) { return newComp(oldComp(state)); };
    }
    return computation;
}

...

stateBind(
  subprocessOne,
  subprocessTwo,
  subprocessThree,
);
```

You can even use `stateBind` to build the various subprocesses from subsubprocesses, and continue down a tree of binding combinators to structure your computation appropriately.

For an explanation of the full, unsimplified State monad, and an excellent introduction to monads in general in JavaScript, see [this blog post](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2011/03/05/translation-from-haskell-to-javascript-of-selected-portions-of-the-best-introduction-to-monads-ive-ever-read/).

Comment: OK, I'll look into that (and comment on it later).  But what do you think about the idea of using the pattern?

Comment: @tieTYT I think the pattern itself is a very good idea; the State monad in general is a useful code-structuring tool for pseudo-mutable algorithms (algorithms that are immutable but emulate mutability).

Comment: +1 for noting that this pattern is essentially a Monad. However, I disagree that it is good idea in a language that actually have mutability. Monad is a way to provide the capability of globals/mutable state in a language that does not allow mutation. IMO, in a language that does not enforce immutability, the Monad pattern is just mental masturbation.

Comment: @LieRyan Monads in general actually have nothing at all to do with mutability or globals; only the State monad specifically does (because that's what it in particular is designed to do).  I also disagree that the State monad is not useful in a language with mutability, although an implementation relying on mutability underneath might be more efficient than the immutable one I gave (although I'm not at all sure about that).  The monadic interface can provide high-level capabilities that are not otherwise easily accessible, the `stateBind` combinator I gave is a very simple example of that.

Comment: @LieRyan I second Ptharien's comment -- most monads are not about state or mutability, and even the one that is, is specifically not about *global* state.  Monads actually work quite well in OO/imperative/mutable languages.

Answer (score 11):

So, there seems to be a lot of discussion between the effectiveness of this approach in Clojure. I think it might be useful to look at Rich Hickey's philosophy as to [why he created Clojure to support data abstractions in this way](http://codequarterly.com/2011/rich-hickey/):

> **Fogus:** So once incidental complexities have been reduced, how can
> Clojure help solve the problem at hand? For example, the idealized
> object-oriented paradigm is meant to foster reuse, but Clojure is not
> classically object-oriented—how can we structure our code for reuse?
>
> **Hickey:** I would argue about OO and reuse, but certainly, being able to
> reuse things makes the problem at hand simpler, as you are not
> reinventing wheels instead of building cars. And Clojure being on the
> JVM makes a lot of wheels—libraries—available. What makes a library
> reusable? It should do one or a few things well, be relatively
> self-sufficient, and make few demands on client code. None of that
> falls out of OO, and not all Java libraries meet this criteria, but many do.
>
> When we drop down to the algorithm level, I think OO can
> seriously thwart reuse. In particular, the use of objects to represent
> simple informational data is almost criminal in its generation of
> per-piece-of-information micro-languages, i.e. the class methods,
> versus far more powerful, declarative, and generic methods like
> relational algebra. Inventing a class with its own interface to hold a
> piece of information is like inventing a new language to write every
> short story. This is anti-reuse, and, I think, results in an explosion
> of code in typical OO applications. Clojure eschews this and instead
> advocates a simple associative model for information. With it, one can
> write algorithms that can be reused across information types.
>
> This
> associative model is but one of several abstractions supplied with
> Clojure, and these are the true underpinnings of its approach to
> reuse: functions on abstractions. Having an open, and large, set of
> functions operate upon an open, and small, set of extensible
> abstractions is the key to algorithmic reuse and library
> interoperability. The vast majority of Clojure functions are defined
> in terms of these abstractions, and library authors design their input
> and output formats in terms of them as well, realizing tremendous
> interoperability between independently developed libraries. This is in
> stark contrast to the DOMs and other such things you see in OO. Of
> course, you can do similar abstraction in OO with interfaces, for
> instance, the java.util collections, but you can just as easily not,
> as in java.io.

Fogus reiterates these points in his book *Functional Javascript*:

> Throughout this book, I’ll take the approach of using minimal data
> types to represent abstractions, from sets to trees to tables. In
> JavaScript, however, although its object types are extremely powerful,
> the tools provided to work with them are not entirely functional.
> Instead, the larger usage pattern associated with JavaScript objects
> is to attach methods for the purposes of polymorphic dispatch.
> Thankfully, you can also view an unnamed (not built via a constructor
> function) JavaScript object as simply an associative data store.
>
> If the only operations that we can perform on a Book object or an
> instance of an Employee type are setTitle or getSSN, then we’ve locked
> our data up into per-piece-of- information micro-languages (Hickey
> 2011). A more flexible approach to modeling data is an associative
> data technique. JavaScript objects, even minus the prototype
> machinery, are ideal vehicles for associative data modeling, where
> named values can be structured to form higher-level data models,
> accessed in uniform ways.
>
> Although the tools for manipulating and accessing JavaScript objects
> as data maps are sparse within JavaScript itself, thankfully
> Underscore provides a bevy of useful opera‐ tions. Among the simplest
> functions to grasp are _.keys, _.values, and _.pluck. Both _.keys and
> _.values are named according to their functionality, which is to take an object and return an array of its keys or values...

Comment: I read this Fogus/Hickey interview before, but I wasn't capable of understanding what he was talking about until now.  Thanks for your answer.  Still not sure if Hickey/Fogus would give my design their blessing though.  I'm concerned I took the spirit of their advice to the extreme.

Answer (score 9):

## The Devil's Advocate

I think this question deserves a devil's advocate (but of course I'm biased).  I think @KarlBielefeldt is making very good points and I'd like to address them.  First I want to say that his points are great.

Since he mentioned this isn't a good pattern even in functional programming, I'll consider JavaScript and/or Clojure in my replies.  One extremely important similarity between these two languages is they're dynamically typed.  I'd be more agreeable with his points if I were implementing this in a statically typed language like Java or Haskell.  But, I'm going to consider the alternative to the "Everything is a Map" pattern to be a traditional OOP design *in JavaScript* and not in a statically typed language (I hope I'm not setting up a strawman argument by doing this, please let me know).

> For example, try to answer the following questions about each subprocess function:
>
> - Which fields of state does it require?
> - Which fields does it modify?
> - Which fields are unchanged?

In a dynamically typed language, how would you normally answer these questions?  A function's first parameter may be named `foo`, but what is that?  An array? An object?  An object of arrays of objects?  How do you find out?  The only way I know of is to

1. read the documentation
2. look at the function body
3. look at the tests
4. guess and run the program to see if it works.

I don't think the "Everything is a Map" pattern makes any difference here.  These are still the only ways I know of to answer these questions.

Also keep in mind that in JavaScript and most imperative programming languages, any `function` can require, modify and ignore any state it can access and the signature makes no difference: The function/method could do something with global state or with a singleton.  Signatures *often* lie.

I'm not trying to set up a false dichotomy between "Everything is a Map" and *poorly designed* OO code.  I'm just trying to point out that having signatures that take in less/more fine/coarse grained parameters doesn't guarantee you know how to isolate, setup and call a function.

But, if you would allow me to use that false dichotomy: Compared to writing JavaScript in the traditional OOP way, "Everything is a Map" seems better.  In the traditional OOP way, the function may require, modify or ignore state that you pass in *or* state that you don't pass in.  With this "Everything is a Map" pattern, you only require, modify or ignore state that you pass in.

> - Can you safely rearrange the order of the functions?

In my code, yes. See my second comment to @Evicatos's answer.  Perhaps this is only because I'm making a game though, I can't say.  In a game that's updating 60x a second, it doesn't really matter if `dead guys drop loot` then `good guys pick up loot` or vice versa.  Each function still does exactly what it's supposed to do regardless of the order they're run.  The same data just gets fed into them at a different `update` calls if you swap the order.  If you have `good guys pick up loot` then `dead guys drop loot`, the good guys will pick up the loot in the next `update` and it's no big deal.  A human won't be able to notice the difference.

At least this has been my general experience.  I feel really vulnerable admitting this publicly.  Maybe considering this to be okay is a *very*, *very* bad thing to do.  Let me know if I've made some terrible mistake here.  But, if I have, it's extremely easy to rearrange the functions so the order is `dead guys drop loot` then `good guys pick up loot` again.  It will take less time than the time it took to write this paragraph :P

Maybe you think "dead guys *should* drop loot first. It would be better if your code enforced that order".  But, why should enemies have to drop loot before you can pick loot up?  To me that doesn't make sense.  Maybe the loot was dropped 100 `updates` ago.  It's not necessary to check if an arbitrary bad guy has to pick up loot that's already on the ground.  That's why I think the order of these operations is completely arbitrary.

It's natural to write decoupled steps with this pattern, but it's difficult to notice your coupled steps in traditional OOP.  If I were writing traditional OOP, the natural, naive way of thinking is to make the `dead guys drop loot` return a `Loot` object that I have to pass into the `good guys pick up loot`.  I wouldn't be able to reorder those operations since the first returns the input of second.

> In an object oriented language, the pattern makes even less sense, because tracking state is what objects do.

Objects have state and it's idiomatic to mutate the state making its history just disappear... unless you manually write code to keep track of it.  In what way is tracking state "what they do"?

> Also, the benefits of immutability go way down the larger your immutable objects get.

Right, as I said, "It's rare that any of my functions are pure".  They *always only* operate on their parameters, but they mutate their parameters.  This is a compromise I felt I had to make when applying this pattern to JavaScript.

Comment: "A function's first parameter may be named foo, but what is that?" That's why you don't name your parameters "foo", but "repetitions", "parent", and other names that make it obvious what's expected when combined with the function name.

Comment: I Have to agree with you on all points. The only problem Javascript really poses with this pattern, is that you are working on mutable data, and as such, you are very likely to mutate state.

There is however, a library that gives you access to clojure datastructures in plain javascript, altough i forget what it's called.

Passing arguments as an object isn't unheard of either, jquery does this multiple places, but documents what parts of the object they use.

Personally though, I would seperate UI-fields and GameLogic-fields, but whatever works for you :)

Comment: @SebastianRedl What am I supposed to pass for `parent`?  Is `repetitions` and array of numbers or strings or does it not matter? Or maybe repetitions is *just* a number to represent the number of repretitions I want?  There's plenty of apis out there that just take an [options](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) object.  The world is a better place if you name things correctly, but it doesn't guarantee you'll know how to use the api, no questions asked.

Answer (score 8):

I have found that my code tends to end up structured like so:

- Functions that take maps tend to be larger and have side effects.
- Functions that take arguments tend to be smaller and are pure.

I didn't set out to create this distinction but that is often how it ends up in my code.  I don't think using one style necessarily negates the other.

The pure functions are easy to unit test.  The larger ones with maps get more into the "integration" test area since they tend to involve more moving parts.

In javascript, one thing that helps a lot is using something like Meteor's Match library to perform parameter validation.  It makes it very clear what the function expects and can handle maps quite cleanly.

For example,

```
function foo (post) {
  check(post, {
    text: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    // Optional, but if present must be an array of strings
    tags: Match.Optional([String])
    });

  // do stuff
}
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#match for more.

:: UPDATE ::

Stuart Sierra's video recording of Clojure/West's ["Clojure in the Large"](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Clojure-Large-scale-patterns-techniques) also touches on this subject.  Like the OP, he controls side effects as part of the map so testing becomes much easier.  He also has a [blog post](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded) outlining his current Clojure workflow which seems relevant.

Comment: I think my comments to @Evicatos will elaborate on my position here.  Yes, I'm mutating and the functions aren't pure. But, my functions are *really* easy to test, especially in hindsight for regression defects I didn't plan on testing.  Half the credit goes to JS: It's very easy to construct a "map"/object with only the data I need for my test.  Then it's as simple as passing it in and checking the mutations.  Side-effects are always represented *in* the map, so they're easy to test.

Comment: I believe pragmatic use of both methods is the "correct" way to go.  If testing is easy for you and you can mitigate the meta problem of communicating required fields to other developers, then that sounds like a win.  Thank you for your question; I've enjoyed reading the interesting discussion you have started.

Answer (score 5):

The main argument that I can think of against this practice is that it's very difficult to tell what data a function actually needs.

What that means is that future programmers in the codebase will have to know how the function being called works internally - and any nested function calls - in order to call it.

The more I think about it, the more your gameState object smells like a global. If that's how it's being used, why pass it around?

Comment: Yes, since I usually mutate it, it IS a global.  Why bother passing it around?  I don't know, that's a valid question.  But my gut tells me that if I stopped passing it, my program would *instantly* become harder to reason about.  Every function could do either *everything* or *nothing* to the global state.  The way it is now, you see that potential in the function signature. If you can't tell, I'm not confident about any of this :)

Comment: BTW: re: the main argument against it: That seems true whether this were in clojure or javascript.  But it's a valuable point to make.  Perhaps the listed benefits far outweigh the negative of that.

Comment: I now know why I bother passing it around even though it's a global variable: It *allows* me to write pure functions.  If I change my `gameState = f(gameState)` to `f()`, it's much more difficult to test `f`.  `f()` may return a different thing each time I call it.  But it's easy to make `f(gameState)` return the same thing every time it's given the same input.

Answer (score 3):

There is more fitting name for what you are doing than [Big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud). What you are doing is called the [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) pattern. It does not look that way at first sight, but in Javascript there is very little difference between

```
update(gameState)
  ...
  gameState = handleUnitCollision(gameState)
  ...
  gameState = handleLoot(gameState)
  ...
```

and

```
{
  ...
  handleUnitCollision: function() {
    ...
  },
  ...
  handleLoot: function() {
    ...
  },
  ...
  update: function() {
    ...
    this.handleUnitCollision()
    ...
    this.handleLoot()
    ...
  },
  ...
};
```

Whether or not is it a good idea probably depends on the circumstances. But it is certainly in line with the Clojure way. One of the aims of Clojure is to remove what [Rich Hickey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Hickey) calls "incidental complexity". Multiple communicating objects is certainly more complex than a single object. If you split functionality into multiple objects, you suddenly have to worry about communication and coordination and dividing responsibilities. Those are complications that are only incidental to your original goal of writing a program. You should see the Rich Hickey's talk [Simple made easy](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy). I think this is a very good idea.

Comment: Related, more general question [https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260309/lightweight-data-modeling-vs-traditional-classes](Lightweight data modeling vs traditional classes)

Comment: "In object-oriented programming, a god object is an object that knows too much or does too much. The god object is an example of an anti-pattern." So god object is not a good thing, yet your message seems to be saying the opposite.  That's a little confusing to me.

Comment: @tieTYT you are not doing object-oriented programming, so it is ok

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion (the "it is ok" one)?

Comment: The problem with God object in OO is that "The object becomes so aware of everything or all the objects become so dependant of the god object that when there is a change or a bug to fix, it become a real nightmare to implement." [source](http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/anti-pattern-god-object) In your code there are is other object beside the God object, so the second part is not a problem. Regarding the first part, your God object *is* the program and your program should be aware of everything. So that's also OK.

Answer (score 2):

I just sorta faced this topic earlier today while playing with a new project. I'm working in Clojure to make a Poker game. I represented face-values and suits as keywords, and decided to represent a card as a map like

```
{ :face :queen :suit :hearts }
```

I could just as well have made them lists or vectors of the two keyword elements. I don't know if it makes a memory/performance difference so I'm just going with maps for now.

In case I change my mind later though, I decided that most parts of my program should go through an "interface" to access the pieces of a card, so that the implementation detail is controlled and hidden. I've got functions

```
(defn face [card] (card :face))
(defn suit [card] (card :suit))
```

that the rest of the program uses. Cards get passed around to functions as maps, but the functions use an agreed-upon interface to access the maps and thus shouldn't be able to mess up.

In my program, a card will probably only ever be a 2-valued map. In the question, entire game state is passed around as a map. Game state will be a lot more complicated than a single card, but I don't think there is fault to raise about using a map. In an object-imperative language I could just as well have a single big GameState object and call its methods, and have the same problem:

```
class State
  def complex-process()
    state = clone(this) ; or just use 'this' below if mutation is fine
    state.subprocess-one()
    state.subprocess-two()
    state.subprocess-three()
    return state
```

Now it's object-oriented. Is there anything particularly wrong with it? I don't think so, you're just delegating work to functions which know how to handle a State object. And whether you're working with maps or objects, you should be wary of when to split it up into smaller pieces. So I say using maps is perfectly fine, as long as you use the same care you would use with objects.

Answer (score 2):

From what (little) I've seen, using maps or other nested structures to make a single global immutable state object like this is fairly common in functional languages, at least the pure ones, especially when using the State Monad as [@Ptharien'sFlame mentioend](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/208178/57138).

Two roadblocks to using this effectively that I've seen/read about (and other answers here have mentioned) are:

- Mutating a (deeply) nested value in the (immutable) state
- Hiding a majority of the state from functions which don't need it and just giving them the little bit they need to work on / mutate

There are a couple of different techniques / common patterns which can help alleviate these issues:

The first is [Zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers): these let one traverse to and mutate state deep within an immutable nested hierarchy.

Another is [Lenses](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html): these let you *focus* into the structure to a specific location and read/mutate the value there. You can combine different lenses together to focus on different things, sort of like an adjustable property chain in OOP (where you can substitute variables for actual property names!)

Prismatic recently did a [blog post](http://blog.getprismatic.com/om-sweet-om-high-functional-frontend-engineering-with-clojurescript-and-react/) on using this sort of technique, among other things, in JavaScript/ClojureScript, which you should check out. They use [Cursors](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Cursors) (which they compare to zippers) to window state for functions:

> Om restores encapsulation and modularity using cursors. Cursors provide update-able windows into particular portions of the application state (much like zippers), enabling components to take references to only the relevant portions of the global state, and update them in a context-free manner.

IIRC, they also touch on immutability in JavaScript in that post.

Comment: The talk OP mentioned also discusses the use of [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) function to limit the scope a function can update to a subtree of the state map. I think nobody brought up this yet.

Comment: @user7610 Good catch, I can't believe I forgot to mention that one -- I like that function (and `assoc-in` et al). Guess I just had Haskell on the brain. I wonder if anyone's done a JavaScript port of it? People probably didn't bring it up because (like me) they didn't watch the talk :)

Comment: @paul in a sense they have because it's available in ClojureScript, but I'm not sure if that "counts" in your mind.  It might exist in PureScript and I believe there's at least one library that provides immutable data structures in JavaScript.  I'd hope at least one of them has these, otherwise they'd be inconvenient to use.

Comment: @tieTYT I had been thinking of a native JS implementation when I made that comment but you make a good point about ClojureScript/PureScript. I should look into immutable JS and see what's out there, I've not worked w/ it before.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a good idea or not will really depend on what you're doing with the state inside those subprocesses. If I understand the Clojure example correctly, the state dictionaries that are being returned are not the same state dictionaries that are being passed in. They are copies, possibly with additions and modifications, that (I assume) Clojure is able to efficiently create because the functional nature of the language depends on it. The original state dictionaries to each function are not modified in any way.

If I'm understanding correctly, you *are* modifying the state objects you pass into your javascript functions rather than returning a copy, which means you are doing something very, very, different from what that Clojure code is doing. As Mike Partridge pointed out, this is basically just a global that you explicitly pass to and return from functions for no real reason. At this point I think it's simply making you *think* you're doing something that you actually aren't.

If you actually are explicitly making copies of the state, modifying it, and then returning that modified copy, then carry on. I'm not sure that's necessarily the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do in Javascript, but it is probably "closeish" to what that Clojure example is doing.

Comment: In the end is it *really* "very, very different"?  In the Clojure example he overwrites his old state with the new state.  Yes, there's no real mutation going on, the identity is just changing.  But in his "good" example, as written, he has no way to get the copy that was passed into subprocess-two.  The identify of that value was overwritten.  Therefore, I think the thing that's "very, very different" is really just a language implementation detail.  At least in the context of what you bring up.

Comment: There are two things going on with the Clojure example: 1) the first example is dependent on the functions being called in a certain order, and 2) the functions are pure so they don't have any side effects. Because the functions in the second example are pure and share the same signature, you can reorder them without having to worry about any hidden dependencies on the order in which they are called. If you are mutating the state in your functions then you don't have that same guarantee. State mutation means your version isn't as composable, which was the original reason for the dictionary.

Comment: You're going to have to show me an example because in my experience with this, I can move things around at will and it has very little effect.  Just to prove it to myself, I moved two random subprocess calls in the middle of my `update()` function.  I moved one to the top and one to the bottom.  All my tests still passed and when I played my game I noticed no ill effects.  I feel my functions are *just* as composable as the Clojure example. We're both throwing away our old data after each step.

Comment: Your tests passing and not noticing any ill effects means that you aren't currently mutating any state that has unexpected side effects in other places. Since your functions aren't pure though you have no guarantee that will always be the case. I think I must be fundamentally misunderstanding something about your implementation if you say that your functions aren't pure but you're throwing away your old data after each step.

Comment: @Evicatos -  Being pure and having the same signature doesn't imply that the order of the functions doesn't matter. Imagine calculating a price with fixed and percentage discounts applied. `(-> 10 (- 5) (/ 2))` returns 2.5. `(-> 10 (/ 2) (- 5))` returns 0.

Comment: @Zak - Ahh yeah that's a good point. I suppose I must be missing something here then but my gut is telling me (possibly incorrectly) that the version with mutating state still isn't equivalent enough to the pure version to be confident in its correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a global state object, sometimes called a "god object", that is passed to each process, you end up confounding a number of factors, all of which increase coupling, while decreasing cohesion. These factors all impact long-term maintainability in a negative way.

**Tramp Coupling** This arises from passing data through various methods that have no need for almost all of the data, in order to get it to the place that can actually deal with it. This kind of coupling is similar to using global data, but can be more contained. Tramp coupling is the opposite of "need to know", which is used to localize effects and to contain the damage that one errant piece of code can have on the whole system.

**Data Navigation** Every sub-process in your example needs to know how to get to exactly the data that it needs, and it needs to be able to process it and perhaps construct a new global state object. That is the logical consequence of tramp coupling; the entire context of a datum is required in order to operate on the datum. Again, non-local knowledge is a bad thing.

If you were passing in a "zipper", "lens", or "cursor", as described in the post by @paul, that is one thing. You would be containing the access, and allowing the zipper, etc, to control reading and writing the data.

**Single Responsibility Violation** Claiming each of "subprocess-one", "subprocess-two" and "subprocess-three" have only a single responsibility, namely to produce a new global state object with the right values in it, is egregious reductionism. It's all bits in the end, isn't it?

My point here is that having all the major components of your game have all the same responsibilities as your game defeats the purpose of delegation and factoring.

**Systems Impact**

The major impact of your design is low maintainability. The fact that you can keep the entire game in your head says that you are very likely an excellent programmer. There are lots of things I have designed that I could keep in my head for the entire project. That is not the point of systems engineering, though. The point is to make a system that can work for something larger than one person can keep in his head **at the same time**.

Adding another programmer, or two, or eight, will cause your system to fall apart almost immediately.

1. The learning curve for god objects is flat (i.e., it takes a very long time to become competent in them). Each additional programmer will need to learn everything that you know, and keep it in their head. You will only ever be able to hire programmers that are better than you, assuming you can pay them enough to suffer through maintaining a massive god object.
2. Test provisioning, in your description, is white box only. You need to know every detail of the god object, as well as the module under test, in order to set up a test, run it, and determine that a) it did the right thing, and b) it didn't do any of 10,000 wrong things. The odds are greatly stacked against you.
3. Adding a new feature requires that you a) go through every subprocess and determine if the feature affects any code in it and vice versa, b) go through your global state and design the additions, and c) **go through every unit test and modify it to check that no unit under test affected the new feature adversely**.

**Finally**

1. Mutable god objects have been the curse of my programming existence, some of my own doing, and some that I have been trapped in.
2. The State monad doesn't scale. State grows exponentially, with all the implications for testing and operations that implies. The way we control state in modern systems is by delegation (partitioning of responsibilities) and scoping (restricting access to only a subset of the state). The "everything is a map" approach is the exact opposite of controlling state.